# Datatables individual column searching without regex option

Tags: jquery, laravel, postgresql, datatables

I'm using [jQuery DataTables API for Laravel](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) and i have to use [Datatables individual column searching](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html).

The problem is the DataTables API for Laravel [doesn't support regex searching with Postgres driver yet](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/regex).

Is there any other search option for datatables other than using regex to bring the exact result of the search?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? To only find rows if the search value matches 100% without any wildcards like `%search term%`?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? Because if I look at all the links you provided it doesn't state that you need to use regex at all.

Comment: @Namoshek is in the question: i have to use outside searching. But it has to be the exact match.

Comment: @Kerel if I have a filter outside with 'P55' and in the column has 'P55' and 'P55 123' will bring both without regex.

Comment: Did you have a look at [custom column filters](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/filter-column)? Sounds exactly like what you need.

Comment: Thank you @Namoshek, you show me the way! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an workaround!

In the ajax config:

```
ajax: {
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: function (d) {
          let filters = []
          $('.selectpicker').each(function () {
            let obj = { 'field': $(this).data('type'),
              'values': $(this).val() };
            filters.push(obj);
          });
          d.data = filters;
        }
      },
```

I added an event 'apply filters' to reload the ajax:

```
App.controlFilters = function (dataTable) {
    $('.apply_filter').on('click', function () {
      dataTable.ajax.reload();
    });
  };
```

In the service:

```
$filters = $request->input('data');
if($filters)
        {
            foreach ($filters as $filter)
            {
                if(!empty($filter['values']))
                {
                    $query->whereIn($filter['field'], $filter['values']);
                }
            }
        }
```